# How can I require a subclass to have a defined variable that can be retrieved with a superclass method?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a simplied programming experience for others to expand my class structure for an app I'm developing. I'm currently working as an intern, but the company I work for wants the final app to have the ability for them to easily add small updates (simple additions that would not necessitate a complete rehire. It's not that they don't want to hire me again.)

I have an abstract class:

```
abstract class ProductEntry {
    protected String title;
    protected String subtitle;
    protected int[] imageArray;
    protected String downloadLink;
    protected String description;

    public ProductEntry() {

    }

    /*
      ~Getters and Setters~
    */
}
```

This is an example class that extends it:

```
public class GenericEntry extends ProductEntry {
    private String newTitle = "This Title";
    private String newSubtitle = "That Subtitle";
    private int[] newImageArray = new int[]{R.drawable.picture1, R.drawable.picture2};
    private String newDownloadLink = "www.google.com";
    private String newDescription = "This is where my description would go, if I had one!";

    public GenericEntry() {

    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        super.setTitle(newTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDownloadLink(String downloadLink) {
        super.setDownloadLink(newDownloadLink);
    }

    @Override
    public void setImageArray(int[] imageArray) {
        super.setImageArray(newImageArray);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
        super.setSubtitle(newSubtitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        super.setDescription(newDescription);
    }
}
```

I'm doing this because then I want to program my app to place all of the subclasses into an an array:

```
ProductEntry allEntries = new ProductEntry[numOfEntries]
```

Then, I will use all the entries to populate a generic layout based upon selection from a list.

```
TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
title.setText(allEntries[position].getTitle());

// Repeat for subtitle and description's TextView, 
// populate ImageViews with pictures from the imageArray, 
// and update the URL link of a button.
```

The reason I chose to do this is that since the people who might wish to update the app in the future will not be programmers and aren't very tech savvy, I can just show them GenericEntry, show them how to copy the class, change the class name, and then just tell them to replace the variables.

This way, they don't need to copy a layout and be forced to create an entirely new activity and assign that to the ListView. I think normally I would create a "unique" (individual) layout for each entry, but since they wish to expand it later with new entries I am trying to create a back-end so they just need to essentially fill-in-the-blank.

This also should allow me to populate the app with information about their product easily.

The problem is, as I'm sure you can tell, that I'm trying to pass variables to subclasses, which you cannot do in Java because that's not how inheritance works. (I hadn't done Java in a while when I started doing this so I didn't realize this mistake right away.)

My question is how can I improve this system while retaining its purpose?

Should I try to forgo the abstract class? I'm newer to android dev so I'm not sure if there is a better way to pass this kind of information to a activity.

Comment: If people are not very tech savy, you should probably find another solution... like creating a `CSV` file with new entries or something they can add to and then put the `CSV` file inside the project and run the app with the new file.
Or better yet, create some kind of web frontend for the users to add entries in and make the app fetch from where the data is saved.
Creating silly code like the above example doesn't make sense. Do it right instead - everyone will be happy in the end :-)

Comment: @Darwind If I were to attempt to use a CSV file, how would I go about parsing it and where would I store this in the android files?

Comment: That's a little bit out of the scope for this question. Open a new question if you want to know how to read from a CSV file or better yet, try to search for it first...

Comment: @Darwind Yea, I didn't know if that would be a big question or not. I ended up looking into it, but thanks for giving me the direction. I'm trying to use OpenCSV as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to require subclasses to provide information, you can use the constructor (in the abstract class):

```
abstract class ProductEntry {
    protected String title;
    protected String subtitle;
    protected int[] imageArray;
    protected String downloadLink;
    protected String description;

    ProductEntry(String title, String subtitle, int[] imageArray, String downloadLink, String description) {
        this.title = title;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
        this.imageArray = imageArray;
        this.downloadLink = downloadLink;
        this.description = description;
    }

    /*
     * ~Getters and Setters~
     */
}
```

This forces subclasses to provide the information, like this:

```
public class GenericEntry extends ProductEntry {
    private static String newTitle = "This Title";
    private static String newSubtitle = "That Subtitle";
    private static int[] newImageArray = new int[]{R.drawable.picture1, R.drawable.picture2};
    private static String newDownloadLink = "www.google.com";
    private static String newDescription = "This is where my description would go, if I had one!";

    public GenericEntry() {
        super(newTitle, newSubtitle, newImageArray, newDownloadLink,newDescription);
    }
}
```